# Linq query not returning anything

Tags: c#, linq

So, I have a `SQL` query that works like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM db.history a
inner join db.history b 
on a.image_id = image_id 
and b.action in(200,201,202)  
where a.user_id = 'someuser'
and a.action in (104) 
and a.time_stamp between '2015-06-22 00:00:00' and '2015-06-22 23:59:59'
```

Now, I am trying to implement the same query in `Linq` in different sections like this:

**1)** First I get everything from the `history` table where the `action = 103 and 104` and that is between the date range:

```
var history = Db.Histories
                          .Select(i => i)   
                          .Where(i
                                  =>
                                     && i.TimeStamp >= startDate && i.TimeStamp <= endDate               
                                     && (i.ActionId == 103 || i.ActionId == 104 ))                                                           
                          .OrderBy(i => i.UserId)                                                       
                          .ToArray();
```

**2)** I get all the users:

```
var users = history.Select(i => i.UserId).Distinct().ToList();
```

These two queries are working fine. However, when I try to loop through all the users to implement the `SQL` query is not returning anything:

```
for(var user in users)
{
    var query = from h in history
                join h2 in Db.Histories.Where(i => i.Action == 200 || i.Action == 201 || i.Action == 202)
                on h.ImageId equals h2.ImageId
                where h.UserId.Equals(user) && h.Action == 104
                select h;
}
```

Why is empty?

Thank you

Comment: Why the inner join with b in the first place? Seems to me that you could just put a.action in(200,201,202) in the where clause instead of b.action in(200,201,202)

Comment: @JoaoFSA. Thanks for your question. You see, I need to find those records where the action was 200, 201 or 202 after that a 104 happened. The 104 happened during that time range.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering h to only have elements `h.Action == 104` and h2 to only have `i.Action == 200 || i.Action == 201 || i.Action == 202` which is a completely different set of results with none of the elements of h.

If `ImageId` is your primary key(or any other unique field) joining 2 different sets of result will always result in empty set

Comment: `ImageId` is not my primary key. An Image might have different `actions` during a time range that's why I am queryng first the 104 to then query 200, 201, 202 that had 104 before.